# Email forwarding in Outlook 2010

Tags: email-client, forwarding

Where do I have to navigate / how can I view and apply email forwarding settings in Microsoft Outlook 2010?

Thanks

Comment: [https://www.google.com/search?q=email+forwarding+outlook+2010&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8](https://www.google.com/search?q=email+forwarding+outlook+2010&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

Open a mail and click the forward button, use the forward button in the quick preview or set up a rule in order to forward specific mails.

The forward button usually has a little blue arrow next to it. For the rule [this](http://www.technipages.com/automatically-forward-email-outlook) could help you out.